# Order by property of nested object with NHibernate Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have class Request with list of Comments. Each Request can have zero, one or many Comments.

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual string Id
    { get; protected set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date
    { get; set; }

    public virtual byte RequestStatusId
    { get; set; }

    public virtual Payment Payment
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RequestComment> RequestComments
    { get; set; }
}
public class RequestComment
{
    public virtual int Id
    { get; protected set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string CommentText
    { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request
    { get; set; }

    public virtual User User
    { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate.Linq to get data from database.
When I sort, for example by Request Id, it looks like this:

```
var query = _session.Query<Request>()
                .Where(r => r.RequestStatusId == requestStatusId)
                .OrderBy(r => r.Id)
                .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);
return query.ToFuture().AsQueryable();
```

When I need last comment for Request I get it like this:

```
public RequestComment GetLastCommentForRequest(string requestId)
{
    var query = _session.Query<RequestComment>()
            .Where(r => r.Request.Id == requestId)
            .OrderByDescending(r => r.Date)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    return query;
}
```

Now I need to get Requests, with their last comment (if exists) and all sorted by CommentText. I was trying to do order in Request query with:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.RequestComments.Where(y => y.Request.Id == x.Id).OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault())
```

But it's not working and I'm getting error »Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.«

**UPDATE**

This is ok, but it's not sorted by last comment, but by first found:

```
.OrderBy(r => r.RequestComments.Select(x => x.CommentText).FirstOrDefault())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
.OrderBy(x => x.RequestComments
                .OrderByDescending(y => y.Date)
                .Select(x => x.CommentText)
                .FirstOrDefault()
        )
```

**UPDATE :**

It seems that linq above translated to query with subquery having order by clause which is not allowed. Try this instead :

```
.OrderBy(x => x.RequestComments
                .Where(y => y.Date == x.RequestComments.Max(o => o.Date))
                .Select(u => u.CommentText)
                .FirstOrDefault()
        )
```

Comment: On SQL Server db I get {"The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."}

Comment: updated my answer with different approach, see if that one works for you.

Comment: on line .Select(x => x.CommentText) I get "A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else..."
When I change it, then y.Date is problem ('string' does not contain a definition for 'Date'...)
I tried to change it into this .FirstOrDefault(y => x.Date == x.RequestComments.Max(o => o.Date))  and there is no error, but it's not sorted.

Comment: sorry i think i was oversimplified the answer. Forgot that at `Select` method all columns except CommentText already stripped out, so I don't have access to Date column in `FirstOrDefault` method. Try to move Date filter before `Select` as in my latest update.

Comment: On Select there must be something else than x, for example .Select(u => u.CommentText)  but it's working :) Thank you!

Comment: This works fine on Sql Server, but unfortunately on Oracle I get invalid identifier error which is due to problem that Oracle doesn't correlate the subqueries nested more than one or two levels (not sure about exact depth).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.RequestComments.Select(y => y.Date).DefaultIfEmpty().Max())
```

Comment: I get {"The DefaultIfEmptyResultOperator result operator is not current supported"} error